# AngularJS bootstrap Select-Picker default value

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using [nya-bootsrap-select select picker](https://github.com/lordfriend/nya-bootstrap-select)

*html*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/lib/selectPicker/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="resources/lib/selectPicker/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/selectPicker/ng-selectpicker-master/src/nya-bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<div class="rangeClass">
    <label for="selectminutes" > Select Range: </label>
    <select class="nya-selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" id="selectminutes"
        ng-model="sp"
        ng-change="update()"
        name="nya-selectpicker"
        ng-selected="selected">
        <option value="5">  5 Minutes</option>
        <option value="10">10 Minutes</option>
        <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
        <option value="20">20 Minutes</option>
        <option value="25">25 Minutes</option>
        <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to be able to have a default value for example "5 Minutes" instead of "Nothing Selected"

[image]

Is there a way to do that? I did try to remove it from library but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this controller code

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.sp=5;

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in HTML:

```
<option value="5" selected="selected">5 Minutes</option>
```

Or you can do this in jQuery:

```
$("select#selectminutes").val("5");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EwDuj/1163/

Comment: Let me know if you need an AngularJS solution too

Comment: Hi Corgin I am using AngularJS but if html does the job, no need for angular solution too

Comment: @Paresh Gami has provided an adequate angular solution if you needed to use that - let me know how you get on

Comment: Yes I saw it and it worked. Thank you both for helping me out!

Comment: No it did not unfortunatelly, I am using both solutions though